# Are all languages in every switch cartidges?

Tags: nintendo-switch

If I buy a Japanese cartridge of a game which is/will be released in Europe, will I be able to play in Eureopean languages?

Comment: Why would region locking have anything to do with languages?

Comment: I didn't mean it that way. Actually I have tested playing with a JP cartridge on my french 3DS (with the tricks to get it region free) and the game actually had french in it (it was with Kirby Plaet Robobot). While the game wasn't release outside of japan, by the way.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the system language to something else in System Settings -> System -> Languages. The language in games such as Zelda will be defaulted to whatever your system language is.

*"If I buy a Japanese cartridge of a game which is/will be released in Europe, will I be able to play in European languages?"*

The answer is **Depending on the game**

Comment: This answer is correct, not sure why the DVs. Whether or not the release of a game on the JP store includes non-Japanese languages will vary from game to game.  There have been examples where English (at least) was included on JP releases, and examples where it wasn't.

Comment: I can confirm that not all cartridges include all languages. At the very least, *Fire Emblem Warriors* has a Japanese voice pack DLC, which is not available (nor necessary or useful) for the Japanese version of the game.